# Differences between axis rotation and rotation angle in object properties

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to wrap my head around rotations in blender. Let's say I have a Cube which I rotate via *Object Properties* where I specify, for example: *Rotation X: 10, Y: 20 and Z: 30*. Now I want to "cancel" X rotation by rotating an object against X axis (select cube, hit <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>) and when I type -10 it doesn't cancel X rotation - that is, it doesn't become zero in object properties, instead in *Object Properties* window it becomes *X: 0.468, Y: 24.7, Z: 26.4*. If I try to manually rotate object back to 0,0,0 rotation angle and rotate manually by -10, -20 and -30 degrees it doesn't arrive to that position either. How can I compute a rotation angle to move back object in that position?

---

The purpose of this manipulation: I set up a camera on some 0,0,z coordinate pointing towards center of coordinates and an object that I rotated against a certain image to have a desired perspective. Now I want to move object back to 0,0,0 position and 0,0,0 rotation while rotating the camera to the opposing angle to maintain original perspective.

After some pondering on the above problem I ended up making a Camera a child of the object that I rotated then manually reset object rotation via object properties to (0,0,0) and then separated Camera from the object while keeping transformation. It did the trick however rotation wasn't what I expected it to be. I tried reading more https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/appendices/rotations.html but I'm still not sure I fully understand it. Is there a good and relatively short explanation of how rotations work in blender and in particular what is the relation of object properties rotation and axis rotation via <kbd>R</kbd> key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale* values you see in the side panel are the **local** properties of the object, that's the reason (or one of them) this tab is titled *Item*. When the cube is not parented to another object then its local rotation (which is local in relation to its superordinate system) is the same as its global rotation - but now it's no longer aligned with the global orientation.

Your *3D Viewport* is usually by default set to *Global* as *Transformation Orientation*. So when you hit <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> you're rotating on **global X**. But as said before, since you've rotated your cube 10°/20°/30° on X/Y/Z it is no longer aligned with the global X axis, so this action results in rotating it **globally** on all its 3 **local** axes - which is why you get three new values in the rotation field.

If you want to rotate along the local X axis you can either switch the *3D Viewport* to local orientation or instead of hitting <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> you can hit the X twice: <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> and it will switch to local rotation.

Repeating to press <kbd>X</kbd> now let's you toggle between local and global. And by the way, if the viewport is set to *Local* orientation, it works the other way round: <kbd>X</kbd> once is local rotation, twice for global and further on for toggling back and forth.

This is also working with translation and scaling. Just a quick note: even though you can switch to *Local* orientation, it is possible that rotating back 10° locally not necessarily sets the X value back to 0°, it could also be 0.000002° or -0.000001° or similar. I guess that's due to floating point imprecisions when rotating not aligned with the global orientation.

[image: local orientation]

[image: global rotation]

[image: local rotation]

[image: global orientation]

Comment: Thank you! I did notice that I can switch to local but was baffled by fraction values, it makes sense now.